Join Layers for PyQGIS
I am using version 3.0 and above. Below is my code where i want to join two layers. I didn't get any error but the Charting Layer doesn't show update on fields. I need to join UPI field of Excel file with CHART_UPI field in tab file.
    @pyqtSlot()
def onAccept(self):
    # Get the selected layers
    vis_layer = self.VIS_Layer.currentLayer()
    charting_layer = self.Charting_Layer.currentLayer()

    if vis_layer is None or charting_layer is None:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'Please select both VIS and Charting layers.')
        return

    # Check if the layers have the required fields
    if not vis_layer.fields().indexFromName('UPI') >= 0 or not charting_layer.fields().indexFromName('CHART_UPI') >= 0:
        # Show error message if the layers don't have the required fields
        QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", "The selected VIS and Charting layers must have 'UPI' and 'CHART_UPI' fields, respectively.")
        return

    # Define join information
    join_info = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
    join_info.setJoinFieldName('UPI')  # VIS column name
    join_info.setTargetFieldName('CHART_UPI')  # Charting column name
    join_info.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
    join_info.setJoinLayerId(vis_layer.id())
    join_info.setPrefix('VIS_')  # Custom prefix for joined fields

    # Perform the join operation
    success = charting_layer.addJoin(join_info)

    if not success:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'Failed to join layers.')
        return

    if success:
        # Update the layer's fields and attributes
        charting_layer.triggerRepaint()
        iface.showAttributeTable(charting_layer)
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Success', 'Join operation completed successfully.')

        # Find unmatched records
        unmatched_upi = findUnmatchedRecords(vis_layer, charting_layer)

        if unmatched_upi:
            self.openUnmatchedDialog(len(unmatched_upi))

It works but supposedly it will automatically update the column field in Charting Layer after it successfully joined but it remains the same. I need to save and close QGIS and open it back then, it reflect the updated VIS column in the Charting Attribute Table. How can i make it automatically show the updated attribute table after it successfully join?

There is one thing you forgot: join_info.setJoinLayer(vis_layer)
